# URL rewriting in VirtualHost causes 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, virtualhost, apache2.4

My frontend server is handled by Apache 2.4.

I would like that when accessing http://198.51.100.13/site1/, it automatically redirects the traffic to my server's port 1001 like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 198.51.100.13
<Directory "/">
Require all granted
</Directory>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/site1(.*)$ http://localhost:1001$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule ^/site2(.*)$ http://localhost:1002$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule ^/site3(.*)$ http://localhost:1003$1 [P,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem: I get this error when opening http://198.51.100.13/site1/:

> 403: Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /areallybigpage on this server.

On the other hand, if I do http://198.51.100.13:1001/, it works (there is a Python serveron port 1001, but this is not important for this question).

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried changing this `RewriteRule ^/site2(.*)$ http://localhost:1002$1 [P,L]` to the format ` http://198.51.100.13:1001/`, i,e, use the IP instead of `localhost`?

Comment: @ildflue yes, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 198.51.100.13
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/site1(.*)$ http://localhost:1001$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule ^/site2(.*)$ http://localhost:1002$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule ^/site3(.*)$ http://localhost:1003$1 [P,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

but don't forget to do:

```
a2enmod proxy  
a2enmod proxy_http       # I forgot this one!
a2enmod proxy_wstunnel   # mandatory if using websockets
service apache2 restart
```